# How does the author extend a function from $M\to M$ to $M^n \to M^n$ in this context?

Tags: model-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding the following proposition:

> Let $\mathcal M$ be an $\cal L$-structure. if $X \subset M^n$ is $A$-definable,
> then every $\cal L$-automorphism of $M$ that fixes A pointwise fixes X setwise
> (that is, if $\mu$ is an automorphism of $M$ and $\mu (a) = a$ for all $a \in A$, then
> $\mu (X) = X$).

If $\mu : M \to M$ is an automorphism of $M$, how is $\mu (X)$ or $\mu (a)$ even defined? $X\subset M^n$ and $A\subset X^l$ in this context for some $n$ and $l$.

Is this an error the author of the book made, or is this standard notation in model theory?

thank you

Comment: You just apply it coordinatewise: $\mu(X)=\{\mu(x_1,...,x_n): (x_1,...,x_n)\in X\}$.

Comment: And yes, this is standard notation in model theory. We also often write $a \in M$ when $a$ is actually a (potentially infinite) tuple, so more accurate would be $a \in M^n$ (or even $a \in M^\alpha$ in the case of infinite tuples).